Couldn't determine repo type for URL: `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
When i am running pod install
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.27.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '10.27.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] Couldn't determine repo type for URL: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 peeraddr=104.26.1.240:443 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
I want to run this commend successfully but didn't worked getting error all the time
